# Static Import file or static import individual items

Tags: java, constants, static-import

Whether I am right or wrong about this I am not sure but SonarLint gives me countless warnings about the repeated use of certain strings.

As a result, I created a constants file purely for Strings in a module that is already accessed in every other module in the project.

My thought was if we are continually being warned about this. It's probably creating each of these strings multiple times and temporarily increasing memory.
(It's a web app, generating JSON and XML with many frequently  repeated terms such as "identity" or "community")

The question I am wondering is, my IDE (IntelliJ) seems to just keep adding the following line:

```
import static com.*****.*****.resources.Constants.*
```

Instead of:

```
import static com.*****.*****.resources.Constants.PARAM_NAME_HASEMAIL;
import static com.*****.*****.resources.Constants.PARAM_NAME_HASSMS;
import static com.*****.*****.resources.Constants.PARAM_NAME_CMD;
```

Bearing in mind the file is currently small with maybe around 100 constants, but that figure will eventually reach 250.

First of all my question is, which of the imports is more efficient, just import the file, import each required constant, or it doesn't matter that much (max will definitely be 250 constants in the file)

The second question I have is, is this worth the effort (easy but grunt work)?
One example is:

```
data.has(PARAM_NAME_OPTIN)
data.remove(PARAM_NAME_OPTIN);
data.put(PARAM_NAME_OPTINTYPE, Coupon.OPTIN_MODE_SINGLE_OPTIN);
```

The above is in maybe 3 or 4 locations in different files. 
The definitions of those 2 constants are:

```
public static final String PARAM_NAME_OPTIN             = "optin";
public static final String PARAM_NAME_OPTINTYPE         = "optInType";
```

The worst offender is below. It is in every single method that makes a call to the backend from the front end (following an ajax request in the browser):

```
json.put(PARAM_NAME_CMD, "Coupon.doSearchCouponEntriesByCoupon");
json.put(PARAM_NAME_APPID, PARAM_NAME_CAMPAIGN);
json.put(PARAM_NAME_COMMUNITYID, session.getAttribute(PARAM_NAME_COMMUNITYID));
json.put(PARAM_NAME_IDENTITYID, session.getAttribute(PARAM_NAME_IDENTITYID));
```

Again the definitions are:

```
public static final String PARAM_NAME_APPID             = "applicationId";
public static final String PARAM_NAME_CMD               = "command";
public static final String PARAM_NAME_CAMPAIGN          = "*****campaign";
public static final String PARAM_NAME_COMMUNITYID       = "communityId";
public static final String PARAM_NAME_IDENTITYID        = "identityId";
```

I have starred the package names to try to obscure the company. Even if this doesn't really share any IP or secrets, better safe than sorry.

I appreciate any feedback you give (good or bad).

Additional info: one of the files I am doing the import manually for each one used currently has 22 imports for those constants.
I guess if the number reaches such heights, then maybe I should switch to the * instead? Or does it still have memory implications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My thought was, if we are continually being warned about this. It's probably creating each of these strings multiple times and temporarily increasing memory. (It's a web app, generating JSON and XML with many frequently repeated terms such as "identityId" or "communityId")

That's actually wrong.  At runtime, all string literals are interned by the class loader.  So, if you have 20 examples of `"identityId"` in many different classes, at runtime you will have only one `String` object that represents all copies of the literal.  (This is NOT an implementation detail.  The JLS guarantees this behavior.)

The real reason for the SonarLint warnings is that having multiple copies of the same string literal is liable to cause maintenance problems.  If you want to change `"identityId"` to `"identityID"`,  you have 20 separate places to change it ... and the IDE is not going to be a lot of help.

> First of all my question is, which of the imports is more efficient, just import the file, import each required constant, or it doesn't matter that much

It has zero impact on runtime performance, and the impact on compilation speeds is most likely insignificant.

The most significant impact of the different styles of `import` is on the readability of your source code, and that is largely a matter of opinion.

> The second question I have is, is this worth the effort?

That is *definitely* a matter of opinion .... in the examples that you presented.

However, if the strings were messages for users to read, then you may need to internationalize them.  If that is the case, then you will be better of storing the strings in (for example) a properties file ... and use different files depending on the user's preferred language.

Finally, assuming that you do decide to use String constants (which is a good idea), I wouldn't recommend putting them all into a big "constants" class.  Define them in ordinary classes and interfaces, according to their purpose.

Comment: Thank you for you the informative answer. You answered what I needed to know.

The values are purely for our purpose. Any messages for the customer are already in properties files and have the correct i18n procedures for our languages.

I am intrigued that the compiler interns all the the Strings so it won't help with mem usage.

However, like you say, from a maintenance POV, it's a good idea as some people on the team are fairly lazy and do lots of copy pasting of methods, entire classes etc. So any chance to ensure these terms are all in one place is beneficial!

Answer (score 1):

Repeated use of the same literal string does not create a memory overhead, since all literal strings in Java source code are [interned](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--). SonarLint warns you not because of memory inefficiency, but because of the risk of errors and reduced readability.

The problem with your proposed solution using static import of the whole class, is that you won't know where the constants came from when you later read the source code where they are used. That's why it's generally preferred to "static import" named fields. But if you have 250 such constants, you might not want to add 250 static import lines to your file.

Instead of naming your constants `PARAM_NAME_APPID` etc., put them in a class called ParamNames. Then you "static import" the class name so you can see where it's come from, and the constants have self-explanatory names:

```
static import package.name.ParamNames;
....
xxx = ParamNames.APP_ID;
```

Comment: Not a bad idea. Since there will be 4 types of constants, however, the main one will be parameter names and have the majority of the 250 (maybe 200 and the other 3 around 15 each)

Answer (score -1):

Refactor the `Constants` class into a property file.

It then contains your constants like this

```
PARAM_NAME_APPID=applicationId
```

you can load it using

```
Properties constants = new Properties();
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("constants.properties")) {
    constants.load(reader);
}
```

Comment: Fair enough. Might be worth doing a one time readon init, multiple getters.
However.... tell me how does that answer my question about static import efficiency OR if the task is actually worthwhile (i.e it will reduce memory footprint)

Comment: Wouldn't that prevent optimizations? E.g. if a constant is an `int`, it can be inlined. It can't if it came from a properties file.

Comment: Also a properties file seems like overkill. These are values that will never change.
The point is, each time these items are created they add more strings to the heap.
If there is a file filled with this strings, they are created once and once only and then just used.

If we have 500 users online, hitting methods. It maybe has to create 50 strings (amongst the strings created by StringBUilder for the full result of a DHTMLX XML tree or JSON data for a form) for each user over the space of a minute.

With a constants file it only has to access those strings.

Comment: @JamieReid Not sure what you're talking about with the heap thing, `Properties` extends `HashMap` so you have a single instance of each `String`; it's pretty much what you suggest in your question with the `data` cache, but without the boilerplate code.

Comment: The other answer make it clear what I mean. 
Plus like I said, properties would be overkill for values that do not change.
We have property files for our configuration and language elements. This is strictly internal data structuring that ultimately the website converts to a visual form or page.